# ionic server livereload fails: websocket Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

Tags: websocket, proxy, ionic2, livereload

I am debugging my ionic 2 application with

```
ionic serve --livereload
```

The debug starts on my chrome browser but livereload does not work (to reflect my changes I have to restart the server). Checking on the chrome debugger, I see this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.2.119:35729/livereload' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.
```

After some research on google, it looks like there might be a problem with ionic working behind a corporate proxy (I am behind a corporate proxy). I am pretty much sure it has to do with the corporate proxy here at work. On my pc at home, I don't have the same problem.

I would very much appreciate if some one could help to figure out why this error and how to fix it. Thanks community.

Comment: Now I have run this command (I have changed the port):
ionic serve -p 8800 -address --livereload

Now I do have a the error on the chrome debugger. But still livereload does not occur after modifification in a source file